# SICStus Prolog - Avoid Redo

Tags: prolog

I'm trying to do a modified version of checkers in prolog. My main cycle is:

```
run(Board, Player) :- write('RUNNING BOARD 1'),nl,
                  canStillPlay(Board, Player),
                 % printBoard(Board),
                  printPlayerTurn(Player),
                  getStartPositions(Player, Board, StartPositions),
                  write('Starting Positions'), nl,
                  write(StartPositions), nl,
                  write('Select Start Position'), nl, nl,
                  read(StartX-StartY),
                  checkValidStartPosition(StartX-StartY, StartPositions),
                 % getEndingPositions(Player, Board, EndingPositions).
                 % write('Ending Positions'), nl,
                 % write('Select Move Position'), nl,
                 % read(EndX-EndY),
                 % checkValidEndingPosition(EndX-EndY, EndingPositions)
                 % movePawn(Board, NewBoard, StartPosition, MovePosition, MovementType, Player),
                  nextTurn(Player, NewPlayer), nl,
                  run(Board, NewPlayer).

run(Board, Player) :- write('RUNNING BOARD 2'), nl,
                  canStillPlay(Board, Player),
                  write('Reselect a pawn'), nl,
                  run(Board, Player).

run(Board,Player) :- write('RUNNING BOARD 3'), nl,
                 Player, !,
                 printBoard(Board),
                 write('White WON').

run(Board,_Player) :- write('RUNNING BOARD 4'), nl,
                  printBoard(Board),
                  write('Black WON').
```

When I select an invalid position, it redoes getStartPositions, instead of just moving on to the next run(Board, Player). I read in another question here that it is "a compiler optimization that a given compiler/version combination might or might not have."

How can I avoid the redo? If I try to cut it, it just ends the program with a no.

Comment: Where are you placing the cut that causes it to just fail?

Comment: Considering I don't want it to run getStartPositions again, I placed it after that, before write('Starting Positions').